# Cost of returning values through calls (Explanation of callvalue gas fee)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

As per the [Ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), it says that calls are 700 gas, however callvalue is 9000 gas. Does this mean that each word returned from a call is 9000 gas? Or even worse, each returned value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "value" in `callvalue` is the amount of ether transferred in a `CALL`. So the 9000 gas charge is for if you send ether along with the call. It's the same 9000 no matter how much ether you're sending.